# catalog_product_save_before event does not fire on $product->save()

Tags: event-observer, product-attribute, products

I need to create a custom attribute for products, which value is updated on product save, based on other attribute's value.

So creating an observer for event `catalog_product_save_before` works fine when saving products manually.

Unfortunately this event doesn't fire when I loop through 100s of products in my shop with:

```
set_time_limit(0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $product) {
    $product->save();
}
```

My test observer function:

```
public function updateProductDetails($observer) {
   Mage::log('inside the observer');
}
```

I need either new event that will fire on `$product->save()` or new method of saving all my products at once, that will fire this event `catalog_product_save_before`.

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: please show you code of catalog_product_save_before event..

Comment: @Amit: I have a whole class there. Multiple attribute updates based on other attributes and product kind. I would prefer not to post it if that's ok.

Comment: You should never call `->save` to update something without calling load before it. calling save from an object inside a collection may lead to loss of data.

Comment: @Marius: that's an interesting point because I think I've lost attribute settings because they were reset to default.

Comment: @Alan. instead of "may lead to loss of data", it should have been "will lead to loss of data".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the comments...
You should never call ->save to update something without calling load before it. calling save from an object inside a collection may lead to loss of data.

If you want to bulk update products you can do this. It's faster and safer.

```
$productIds = an array with product ids to update
$values = array('attr_code_one' => 'value 1', 'attr_code_two' => 'value 2', ....);
$storeId = 0; //store id for which you need the changes. 0 means default values.
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    $productIds,
    $values,
    $storeId
);
```

Comment: thanks. What if I'd like to set different attribute value for each product. Would this be the best way? `foreach($pids as $pid) { $values = getValuesByPid($pid);  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($pid, $values, $storeId); }`

Comment: Yep...for each different values you want to update you need to call `updateAttributes`.  but one small change. The first parameter must be an array. So instead of `updateAttributes($pid, ...)` use `updateAttributes(array($pid), ...`

Comment: Thanks Marius. I've accepted your answer because you found another issue I was not aware of(using 'save' method) and solved it with different code. Adarsh answer was also correct because it answered my question directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily fire a new or same event as magento does from your function.

To fire event try this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $product) {
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_save_before', array('product' => $product));
    $product->save();
}
```

**However, if you are trying to do some other stuff on `product save` why not have that code right with your loop? This will not need to fire any event.**

I haven't tested but should work.

Comment: Thanks Adarsh. I got this error: 'Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Mage::dispatchEvent() must be of the type array, object given.' I'm just wondering what kind of array I need to pass - I'm looking into that now but if you know feel free to share :).

Comment: Check I have updated.

Comment: This seems to help but I have another small issue with this code, attribute's values aren't correct. I need to debug and see where's the problem.

Comment: the product are resaved but with incorrect attribute values and my observer method doesn't run. I have place `Mage::log()` inside it and it didn't work.

Comment: is that loop is also called from observer?

Comment: no, the loop is called directly from a file in root folder(I just need to use it once).

Comment: Can you add the observer function?

Comment: I've just added a simple logging test and it, surprisingly, does not fire within the loop. So the rest of the code doesn't work too.

Comment: I would again recommend having that observer code right with your loop, which is faster/safer and no need to fire event as well.